# How to use svg with geom_image in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

I like to use some icons and images in my `ggplot`, thus use the `ggimage` package. I can make it work with local or online images in `.png` format. But it does not work with `svg` such as https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ionic-team/ionicons/main/src/svg/hourglass.svg Initially I also was trying a `geom_icon()` layer.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(am = factor(am)) %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% 
  mutate(image = c("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png",
              "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(am), y=avg_mpg)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) + 
  geom_image(aes(image=image), size=.2) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share what not working? When I use the link it shows the icon.

Comment: Works fine for me, too: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XwQg.png. Only had to manually install `rsvg`. If it matters I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Thank you, I missed the `rsvg` package. Obviously did not install all dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `rsvg` package with all dependencies.